# wget: download a website which is password protected using a form

Tags: authentication, wget

I have a problem with downloading a website using `wget`.

First I need to login to the website with a username and password:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies 
     --post-data="strUser=username&strPW=password" 
     http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/nixlog.asp
```

Then I try to download the complete website http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/ :

```
wget -k -r -m -np --load-cookies cookies.txt 
     http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/80_01_member.asp
```

I get a response saying that I am not logged in then it redirects me to:

```
http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/nixlog.asp?grund=notloggedin
```

Any ideas?

**HttpFox**

```
00:00:07.712    0.193   597 301 POST    302 Redirect to: 80_01_member.asp   http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/login.asp
00:00:07.943    0.255   481 11957   GET 200 text/html   http://hostname/wwwawelle/member/80_01_member.asp
00:00:08.232    0.060   428 (6054)  GET (Cache) text/css    http://hostname/wwwawelle/style.css
00:00:08.260    0.051   420 (589)   GET (Cache) application/x-javascript    http://hostname/wwwawelle/news/jscr_inc.js
```

*Cookies*

```
ASPSESSIONIDCSATRCQQ    APPIOGADBMLHOMFHCALPBFNL    /   hostname    End Of Session
```

*POST Data*

```
strUser username
strPW   password
Abschicken  Anmelden
```

**wget cookies.txt**

```
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2011-03-28 14:23:17.
# Edit at your own risk.

hostname    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   ASPSESSIONIDCSATRCQQ    EBAJOGADDHGHCANLKJCMDCPP
```

Comment: Is there any javascript on the site that might be getting in the way? Also could the site be checking the REFERER?

Comment: Is your cookies.txt populated?

Comment: After logging-in with wget, do the contents of `cookies.txt` look sensible?

Comment: so here some inputs...

Comment: were you able to success in this?

Answer (score 2):

If the site is saving the session with cookies you can log on using a browser, then have wget use the appropriate cookie to continue accessing the site. However, if the site uses other means, such as PHP $_SESSION variables you're out of luck.

If this is a site to which you have legitimate access surely you can configure other access means. On the other hand, if you don't have legitimate access and are merely trying to leach someone else's site, which is the impression I get from your question, I hope you fail.

Comment: Re PHP session variables, I think that any data in $_SESSION will rely on a session-id stored in a cookie (or optionally in the URL) so that might not be a problem

Comment: @grojo, that cookie is in memory, not in a file, so it's kind of hard to pass on to wget.

Comment: the session data is on the server, however the session ID is stored in the cookie, and AFAIK wget _will_ save it to disk if told to. One possible tip is to GET the page with the form first to aquire/initialize any session data, before attempting to POST login data to the form URL.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the site is checking `referer`, `user-agent`, etc.

Check out the *HttpFox* and *Tamper Data* Firefox plugins. They let you see/manipulate data going to/from any server. Make sure you note any redirects and cookies coming from the server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this before the URL:

`wget username:password@http://me.com/me.html`

Comment: Looks like the site is password protected using a form, not basic auth.

Comment: FYI: The form for basic auth is http://username:password@example.com/me.html